# Flutter - How to make custom bottom navigation bar

Tags: flutter

Can anyone help me how to achieve this custom bottom navigation bar in my app? I am new to flutter.

[image: custom]

Comment: Use this package https://pub.dev/packages/animated_bottom_navigation_bar

Comment: Basically image consists of two parts one is bottom navigation bar..and other is floating action button in center..the fab only need to desgin as per your heart shape

Comment: how can I design FAB in that shape? could you help me?

Comment: make a custom widget of heart shape button with the child as a home icon and set it as a FAB in the bottom bar.